# BottomTabNavigation style dose not fit what i want and make empty withes areas

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to make the tab bar a little be up and be round at bottom of the screen but when you apply the margin it left a white area and other components like scrollview cant show in this area .

[image: red view can expand under tabbar]

i tried zIndex But the white areas are attached to tab bar and cant be handled by styling it

```
this is option for bottomtabbar including the style of tabbar .


    const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeStack,
    LinksStack,
    SettingsStack,
    },
    { 
      tabBarOptions: {
         initialRouteName: 'HomeStack',
         activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
         inactiveTintColor: '#ddd',
         style: {
         borderRadius:30,
         marginBottom:25,
         marginHorizontal:10,
         backgroundColor: '#4d535e',
         // shadowColor:'#4d535e',
         justifyContent:'flex-start',
         alignContent:'flex-start',
         alignItems:'flex-start',
         // zIndex: 50,
         alignSelf:'flex-start',
         safeAreaInset:{}
        }
     }
    }
```

if i want say what the result should be the pinterest app has a bottom tab bar like what i want ...
[image: desire outcome like pinterest]

Comment: actually this a good pricatise after completing style you can do animation that a big challeng

Answer (score 0):

After a lot off struggling i found out that solution is quiet simple. u just need give the TabBar component style,these following code (add beside other styles).

```
{...other styles
 bottom:20,
 zIndex:1,   
 position:'absolute',
}
```

Comment: if any one want to do it like pinterest style and animation (check on app) just messege me

Comment: Hello @mohsean can you tell me how implement pinterest like animation in react native?